# Particle in a gravitational field moving at constant speed in some inertial frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

While working on an unrelated problem I found an interesting result which I presume must already be known, but I cannot find any reference to it. It is the following:

*Consider a small particle P moving in the gravitational field of a large punctual mass M placed at point O - assume the mass of the particle is negligible compared to M, so the trajectory of P is exactly a conic curve with one of its foci at O. Then there is an inertial frame where the speed of P is constant.*

How well known is this? Does anybody know of a reference for it?

Comment: Do you mean inertial in the Newtonian sense of motion with a constant velocity, or the relativistic sense of motion along a spacetime geodesic?

Comment: In GR, the rest frame of that particle would be inertial since it's in free fall.

Comment: Inertial in the Newtonian sense, i.e. how the motion of the particle would look when observed from some frame moving at a constant velocity.

Comment: It's true and well known since about two centuries. For an extensive
bibliography look in Google "hodograph keplerian motion"

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem, in speed space we just add the velocity at the center of the hodograph, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question deserves a correct answer on record: The result is a trivial consequence of the circularity of Keplerian motions, a fact known and rediscovered several times along the last two centuries - see e.g. David Derbes, Reinventing the wheel: Hodographic solutions to the Kepler problems, American Journal of Physics 69, 481 (2001); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1333099

Comment: Credit due to Elio Fabri for his comment that lead me in the right direction to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be true. Acceleration is the same in all frames moving at constant velocity. In order for what you say to be true, there must always be at least one frame in which the acceleration is perpendicular to the velocity at every point in the trajectory. But the only thing you can do by changing frames is add a constant velocity vector to every point on the trajectory.

For any trajectory, the velocity and acceleration vectors are already perpendicular at the point of closest approach to O. If your frame velocity is not either parallel or antiparallel with the velocity vector of P at the point of closest approach, then the velocity and acceleration vectors at this point will cease to be perpendicular (because you will have added a component to the velocity that is parallel to the acceleration). So your frame must move either parallel or antiparallel to the velocity vector at closest approach.

But this presents another problem, because this shift must apply to all points on the trajectory. For every conic section except a circle (which has constant speed in the reference frame stationary with respect to O), the velocity and acceleration vectors are not perpendicular at nearly all points on the trajectory; in fact, this is true for all but a finite set of points. In order to *make* them perpendicular, a velocity vector must be added which is (anti-)parallel to the acceleration vector (and has the right magnitude to cancel out this parallel component of the velocity).

But we have already established that our frame velocity vector is (anti-)parallel to the velocity vector at closest approach. So, in order for what you say to be possible, two conditions must be fulfilled by the trajectory:

- The acceleration vector must be *perpendicular* to the velocity vector at closest approach, and
- The acceleration vector must be *parallel* to that same vector almost everywhere else, which includes points arbitrarily close to the point of closest approach.

Due to the continuity of the velocity and acceleration vectors as a function of time, this kind of abrupt jump cannot happen. Therefore, it is impossible to find a frame that will produce a constant speed.

Comment: Certainly in this problem the condition *the speed of P is constant* is equivalent to *the trajectory of P is perpendicular to OP at all times*, but perpendicularity may not remain invariant among different inertial frames. Take for instance the points where the latus rectum intersects the (conic) trajectory in the frame where O is at rest. Project the velocity of P at those points onto the latus rectum (the projection is the same). Change to the frame moving with a velocity equal to that projection. Now the trajectory of P is perpendicular to the line of the latus rectum (which goes thru O).

Comment: Anyway, I arrived at this result starting at the other end, I was studying the movement of a point P that travels at a constant speed in a trajectory always perpendicular to OP, with O moving at constant velocity. When I looked at P's motion in the frame where O is at rest I found it to be identical to that of particle moving in a gravitational field created by a mass at O. I though this was something already known, but cannot find any reference to it.